# Работа с двумя функциями

Tags: python, функции, циклы

Я работаю с API финансовой биржи.
Мне необходимо выполнить три действия
1) Однократно совершить действие, покупку
2) Получить данные об этом действии
3) Работать с этими данными по циклу, раз в минуту, в течение часа

Я хотел бы сделать это двумя функциями

```
def action():
    my_action = ...
    my_data = ....
    return my_data

def info(data):
    for _ in range (60):
    my_info = data * 2
    print (my_info)

info(data=action())
```

В принципе, это работает, action выполняется один раз, а info - много раз, но выглядит эта запись как-то не логично, и если добавить больше переменных, то все может усложниться. Есть более правильные, логичные методы для моей задачи.

Comment: Рекомендую почитать про рефакторинг кода и шаблоны проектирования (design patterns). Возможно, там есть то, что вам нужно

Comment: Передавать результат одной функции в качестве параметра другой вполне нормально.

Comment: Сделай несколько потоков Модуль threading [Мануал](https://geekbrains.ru/posts/python_threading_part1)